# Jar/code Singing certificate is expired and same certificate is renewed

Tags: jar, certificate, jarsigner

I have web application, which is expired and renewed the same certificate and signed some part. Can it work?

Suppose I have a.jar, b.jar and c.jar in my WEB-INF\lib and **all jars have same package**. Those are signed  with certificate **C1**. Now certificate (C1) is **renewed** and only c.jar is signed with renewed certificate. Can this work in web application?

Or how to renew certificate to work above case?

Answer (score 0):

It is confirmed that all the jar files need to be signed again if certificate is renewed and if some jar is changed and built and signed with renewed certificate then all jar files need to be signed(Package is shared with other jar files which signed with older certificate.)